# Отловить клик по браузеру c#

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser

Как можно отловить нажатие на браузер ? даже в пустое место ? Пока использую метод `webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted` , но он работает только, если я спровоцирую переход на другую страницу.

Comment: Подписать [WebBrowser.Document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.document(v=vs.110).aspx) на событие [Click](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.click(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov я не особо понял, как это сделать, можете привести пример ? спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подписать [WebBrowser.Document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.document(v=vs.110).aspx) на событие [Click](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.click(v=vs.110).aspx).

Делать это нужно после завершения загрузки. То есть предварительно должна быть сделана подписка на событие `DocumentCompleted`.

```
webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted;

webBrowser1.Navigate("google.ru");


private void WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.Document.Click += Document_Click;
}

private void Document_Click(object sender, HtmlElementEventArgs e)
{
    // произошёл клик по браузеру
}
```